# Override EDMX behavior

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, edmx

I'm updating model from database with a table.
The table has a computed field ( SomeFiled ISNULL(column1,column2))

When the table is imported to edmx this field is set a key field.
This configuration causing me troubles.

I changed it manually but I'm working on the project with other people and would like to prevent a case in which someone updates the model and will forget to change the field.

Is there a way to set some post update actions on edmx or some other workaround?

Thanks in advance and kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for your situation, you can use same concept for your case.

In your dbcontext sub class, override OnModelCreating and add a new configuration like this;

```
       protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
           modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BankAccountEntityTypeConfiguration());
       }
```

Also create e configuration class like the following;

```
       class BankAccountEntityTypeConfiguration:EntityTypeConfiguration<BankAccount>
       {
          public BankAccountEntityTypeConfiguration()
          {
              //key and properties

              this.HasKey(ba => ba.Id);

              this.Property(ba => ba.Balance)
                  .HasPrecision(14, 2);

              //associations
              this.HasRequired(ba => ba.Customer)
                  .WithMany()
                  .HasForeignKey(ba => ba.CustomerId)
                  .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

              this.HasMany(ba => ba.BankAccountActivity)
                  .WithRequired()
                  .HasForeignKey(ba => ba.BankAccountId)
                  .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
           }
         }
```

and also you can use something like this inside the configuration;

```
         this.Property(t => t.Sum)
             .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Which should I use to set the property Entity Key to false?

Comment: if I understood it correctly, this will help..
`modelBuilder.Entity<AnEntity>().Property(p => p.a_key_field)   .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);`